# Adding Exchange Account to Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013

I have three VMs running on VMWare ESXi: Domain Controller, Exchange Server 2013 and desktop with Outlook 2013. All of them running Windows Server 2012.
OWA works fine, but when I'm trying to use Outlook i get:

> The action cannot be completed.  The connection to Microsoft Exchange
>   is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this
>   action.

All machines are in domain (lab.local). Tried running on Exchange server `Test-MAPIConnectivity -Identity "administrator@lab.local"` on Exchange Management console - result is success. Also all DNS entries are seem to be fine.
What should I do next? Maybe I should set up autodiscover (if it's necessary)?

Comment: Autodiscover is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cname or autodiscover record setup. Also need to configure outlook anywhere.